# Countdown Timer Unable to Work Properly In Chrome Extension Popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, popup

I'm building a popup chrome extension that works as a countdown timer, but it is not working as intended. When a user inputs a certain amount of minutes, for instance, seconds will immediately turn to 59 and begin decrementing, but minutes will remain static. The same happens with hours.

This is my html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="../stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Study Break Chrome Extension</title>
        <!-- <script src="jquery.js"></script> -->
        <script src="../popup-script.js"></script>
        <script src="../background.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="timer.html"></script> -->
        <style>
            body {
              font-family: "Monaco", monospace;
              color: #003c00;
              background-image: url('/media/bg2.JPEG');
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              background-attachment: fixed; 
              background-size: cover;
            }
            html, body {
                text-align: center;
                width: 325px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Study Break!</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="work">
                <h2 class = "idk">Set A Break Every...</h2> 
                <p id="workhrlabel" class="workhrlabel">Hours</p>
                <p id="workminlabel" class="workminlabel">Minutes</p>
                <p id="workseclabel" class="workseclabel">Seconds</p>
                <input id="work-hours" type="number" max="99" min="0" value="0" class="worktime">
                <p id="p1" class="semicolon">:</p>
                <input id="work-minutes" type="number" max="60" min="0" value="0" class="worktime">
                <p id="p2" class="semicolon">:</p>
                <input id="work-secs" type="number" max="60" min="0" value="0" class="worktime">
            </div>
            <div id="break">
                <h2>For...</h2>
                <p id="break-hour-label" class="break-label">Hours</p>
                <p id="break-min-label" class="break-label">Minutes</p>
                <p id="break-sec-label" class="break-label">Seconds</p>
                <input id="break-hours" type="number" max="99" min="0" value="0" class="breaktime">
                <p id="p1" class="semicolon">:</p>
                <input id="break-minutes" type="number" max="60" min="0" value="0" class="breaktime">
                <p id="p2" class="semicolon">:</p>
                <input id="break-secs" type="number" max="60" min="0" value="0" class="breaktime">
            </div>
            <div class = "btns">
                <button id="set" class="btn">Set</button>
                <button id="reset" class="btn">Reset</button>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My popup-script:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    document.getElementById('set').addEventListener('click', function(){
        let selHrs = document.getElementById('work-hours').value;
        let selMins = document.getElementById('work-minutes').value;
        let selSecs = document.getElementById('work-secs').value;

        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({name: 'Timer', hours: selHrs, mins: selMins, secs: selSecs});
});
})

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, _, _){
    if (request.name == 'updateTimer') {
      
        document.getElementById('work-hours').setAttribute('value', request.hours);

        document.getElementById('work-minutes').setAttribute('value', request.mins);
        console.log(request.mins)
        document.getElementById('work-secs').setAttribute('value', request.secs);

    }

});
```

And my background-script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    let set = document.getElementById('set');

    let hours = request.hours;
    let mins = request.mins;
    let secs = request.secs;
 
    let startTimer = undefined;

    if (request.name == "Timer"){
  
        function countdown(hr,mm,ss)
        {
        var interval = setInterval(function(){

            if(hr == 0 && mm == 0 && ss == 0)clearInterval(interval);
            
            if(ss == 0)
            {
                ss = 59;
                
                if(mm == 0)
                {
                    mm = 59;
                    if (hr != 0) {
                        hr--;
                    }
                    
                }
                else {
                    mm--;
                }
            } else {
                ss--;
            }
        console.log("hours" + hr + "minutes: " + mm + " secondsL " + ss); 
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({name: 'updateTimer', hours: hr, mins: mm, secs: ss});
        },1000)
        }
        countdown(hours, mins, secs)
    }
})
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, I just fixed it!

Comment: you are expecting to have a countdown based on real time values with just a simple setInterval ? (this is impossible!)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. It actually works when it's run, and it seems to display properly when the popup is clicked off and then clicked again. It's just not immediate

Comment: The duration argument of setInterval is just an indication of the waiting time period proposed to the system, and the system sets this callback according to its availability on the other tasks it accomplishes, and this time is never precisely respected. If you do this reminder every second over an hour, then the time measurement can easily exceed 5 to 10 minutes, or even more.

Comment: The countdown function isn't actually mine (the one I wrote was worse), but I assume there's no simple solution anyways? (this is a project due in a few hours).

Comment: there are many countdown related questions here, some are even very detailed, why not take a look (and this is what you are supposed to do before posting, to find out if your question is relevant or not. .)

Comment: Alright, thank you!